# How can I check Koin modules while using injection parameters?

Tags: kotlin, koin

I would like to check my configuration by using the `checkModules()` method provided by `koin-test` as explained [here](https://beta.insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-core/index.html#_checking_your_koin_configuration).

However, I am using [injection parameters](https://beta.insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-core/index.html#_injection_parameters) and my test fails with an exception:

```
org.koin.core.error.NoParameterFoundException: Can't get parameter value #0 from org.koin.core.parameter.DefinitionParameters@3804648a
```

Here is a simple test to demonstrate the issue:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.koin.dsl.koinApplication
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.check.checkModules

class TestCase : KoinTest {
    @Test
    fun checkModules() {
        koinApplication {
            modules(
                module { factory { (msg: String) -> Message(msg) } }
            )
        }.checkModules()
    }

    data class Message(val message: String)
}
```

Is there a way to make this work? How could I provide the missing parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass this parameter to your test, like this:

```
class TestCase : KoinTest {
    @Test
    fun checkModules() {
        koinApplication {
            modules(module { factory { (msg: String) -> Message(msg) } })
        }.checkModules {
            create<Message> { parametersOf("testMessage") }
        }
    }


    data class Message(val message: String)
}
```

Example from Koin repository: [CheckModulesTest.kt#L156](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/koin-test/src/test/kotlin/org/koin/test/CheckModulesTest.kt#L156)

My issue with the same question: [Issue](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/473)

Comment: Since create is deprecated, one should use withParameters instead of create to get same functionality. Note that withParameter and withParameters are different methods.